# Auth0 Authentication API with React Native

Tags: react-native, auth0

I am currently developing a mobile app in react native and using Auth0 for user management.  I am using my own login, signup and forgot password screens instead of their lock widget.  I was able to implement passwordless sms and email by calling their authentication api as well as account linking by using their management api. However, I am having difficulty authenticating in a user with their email and password through the api once they already have an account.  It seems to me that there should be a single endpoint for this in which you include the email and password in the body of the request.  I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to simply login users using auth0's api.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [authentication workflow is covered here](https://auth0.com/docs/client-auth/current/client-side-web)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this react native (embedded login custom UI) sample (slightly dated) - wrote it around 6 months ago, but it should offer you good insights - https://github.com/auth0-samples/react-native-embedded-login

Sign in logic is [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/react-native-embedded-login/blob/master/actions/auth/index.js#L31)

Feel free to leave questions below.

Comment: Wow that works great.  I find it amazing that there is little to no reference of this in their docs.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most welcome, agreed. Auth0 tends to promote using a user agent overlay (browser + redirection) for mobile, and most of the quickstarts and samples today focus on that.

Comment: @arcseldon I'm trying to implement a custom login using Auth0 in my React Native app. I've looked at your code samples and though they look nice and easy to follow, your code doesn't seem to be using the `PKCE` approach. Isn't the `PKCE` approach the recommended and secure approach which I think requires a few roundtrips to Auth0 API in order to increase security?

Comment: Found the documentation for this endpoint here: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?javascript#resource-owner-password

Comment: There is also this documentation: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-resource-owner-password-flow

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still looking there is this step by step on their website on how to login with password via API: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-resource-owner-password-flow

And with this endpoint you can register a new account: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#signup